# ReactJS component/library for building a real estate plan

Tags: library, javascript, diagram, react, component-diagram

We have to provide our customers possibility to make such real estate plan(picture below) for renting trade space, shapes could be of different form and could be grouped. Would be great to have the ability to set real size (e.g. meter), could you advise the right component or library capable to do so?

[image: plan]

Comment: Would you accept plain JS?

Answer (score 1):

[Diagram](https://nam02.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.syncfusion.com%2Freact-ui-components%2Freact-diagram&data=04%7C01%7Cnaganathanganeshbabu%40syncfusion.com%7C7106ab0c3c784033593208d8d950ce89%7C77f1fe12b04949198c509fb41e5bb63b%7C0%7C0%7C637498288370371740%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=Pvoxtb%2FYAA5Pb%2Bzl5tWDLhFK6TPKAuiIH6BVNdaqbKU%3D&reserved=0) is a feature-rich react component for visualizing, creating, and editing interactive diagrams like flow charts, organizational charts, mind maps, BPMN diagrams, and more. Its rich feature set includes built-in shapes, editing, serializing, exporting, printing, overview, data binding, and automatic layouts.

Herewith we have a created a simple sample to achieve such a real estate plan(picture below) for renting trade space with Diagram’s [Nodes](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/diagram/nodes/).

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cxavth-kspej5

More Examples: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/#/material/diagram/default-functionality

For further information, please refer our [help documentation](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/diagram/getting-started/)
The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license program](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: $ 995 /developer 1st year $445 /2nd year - for the gig buys, BUT,  `Companies and individuals with less than $1 million USD in annual gross revenue and 5 or fewer developers` can use the full, free [community edition](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense). Looks excllent, thanks